# Not finding saleID for some reason. the class calls it though

Tags: java, try-catch

Having problems now, i changed it to accept try and catch and now its not finding the sales ID to compare.

Is anyone able to see what is happening?
has it got something to do with how getSaleID is called?

```
private static void submitOffer() throws OfferException
{

  int offerPrice;
  boolean offerAccepted;

  System.out.print("Enter sale ID: ");
  String saleID = keyboard.nextLine();
  try
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < salesCount; i++)
     {
        if ( sales[i].getSaleID().equalsIgnoreCase(saleID))
        {   
           System.out.print("Enter offer price: ");
           offerPrice = keyboard.nextInt();
           keyboard.nextLine();
           System.out.println();
           //try!!!
           offerAccepted = sales[i].makeOffer(offerPrice);
           if (offerAccepted == true)
           {
              System.out.print("Offer was accepted"); 

              if(offerPrice <= sales[i].getReservePrice())
              {
                 System.out.print("Reserve Price was met");

              }
              else
              {
                 System.out.print("Reserve Price was not met");
              }
           }
           else
           {
              System.out.print("Offer was not accepted");
           }

        }

     } // for
  }
  catch(OfferException e)
  {
     System.out.print("That property with the sale ID " + saleID + "Does not exist");
     System.out.println();
  }
```

}

Comment: Do you get some exception?

Comment: nope, just says its true all the time

Comment: What is the question? All we know is, from your comment, that it always "says its true". What does that mean? I can't find any `System.out.println("its true")` in the code, and I can't read in your mind. What do you expect this code to do, with which inputs, and what does it do instead?